# How to remove words not in caps in R?

Tags: r, tm, stringi

I'm doing text analysis using R. Is there a way to remove all the words not in caps using `tm` or `stringi`?

If I have something like this

```
Albert Einstein went to the store and saw his friend Nikola Tesla ... + 200 pags
```

to be converted into

```
Albert Einstein Nikola Tesla
```

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `grep` and a regular expression:

```
words <- 'Albert Einstein went to the store and saw his friend Nikola Tesla'

# split to vector of individual words
vec <- unlist(strsplit(words, ' '))
# just the capitalized ones
caps <- grep('^[A-Z]', vec, value = T)
# assemble back to a single string, if you want
paste(caps, collapse=' ')
```

Answer (score 8):

You could just remove those words using a simple regex

```
gsub("\\b[a-z]+\\s+", "", x)
# [1] "Albert Einstein Nikola Tesla"
```

This is just looking for a word boundary > low case letter > all the letters after it > all the spaces after it and removes it

---

Though in cases you have words such as `don't`, you would need a bit more complicated regex. Something like

```
x <- "if Albert Einstein didn't see his friend Nikola Tesla leavin'"
gsub("\\b[a-z][^ ]*(\\s+)?", "", x)
# [1] "Albert Einstein Nikola Tesla "
```

Comment: `(\\s+)?` is also known as `\\s*` :) the extra space is annoying - not obvious how to fix in a single regex (without making a complete mess out of it)

Comment: @eddi, yeah thanks- though not sure if any better. Regarding the extra space- it will only happen in that certain case when there some punctuation at the end of the whole document, but I guess it's not such a big loss for the OP, eh?